# Passing a parameter through URL via loop

Tags: python, django

So, I'm trying to pass the name of the PDF to the URL so that the view can display the relevant PDF.

urls.py

```
path('show-invoice/<str:invoice>', views.pdf_view, name ="pdfview")
```

views.py

```
def pdf_view(request, invoice):
    invoicename = Laptop.objects.get(invoice=invoice)
    invoicename = invoicename.invoice
    pdfpath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + invoicename
    pdfpath = pdfpath.replace('/', '\\')
    try:
       return FileResponse(open(pdfpath, 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
    except FileNotFoundError:
       raise Http404()
```

models.py

```
invoice = models.FileField(default='default.pdf', upload_to='uploads/')
```

invoice_list.html

```
<h2>View invoices</h2>
{%for i in invoices%}
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href = "{%url 'laptops:pdfview' invoice=i.invoice%}"> {{i.invoice}} </a>
   </li>
</ul>
{%endfor%}
```

Now, my question is: Why does it work when I use `invoice='default.pdf'` and not when I use`invoice=i.invoice`? I get the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /invoices/
Reverse for 'pdfview' with keyword arguments '{'invoice': 'uploads/default1.pdf'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['show\\-invoice\\/(?P<invoice>[^/]+)$']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `str`  converter you have used in the path does not match the `\` in your invoice attribute.

You can use the [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) converter instead:

```
path('show-invoice/<path:invoice>', ...)
```

Comment: Wow. Never would have picked up on that. Thanks, Daniel!